# Google Analytics: My paid search conversion fall over 15% from september and on?

Tags: google-analytics

In my acquisition channel report I noticed that my conversions from paid search is making a drastic change in September and on.

In the picture I have september-january(2020) on top and april-august below. As you see from september and to now only 2.3% from paid search is converting. A big chance compared to the 19% before september.

My budget is completely the same and I have not made any changes to my site. My site: Travelit.dk is a SPA and I have several issues reading my analytic.

Any updates thats influences this matter or do you have any suggestions on what this could be?

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfxOV.png)

Comment: All channels have gone down, not just paid. Is it just Analytics not tracking revenue or is the drop in sales also effective in your CRM?

Comment: Hello @MichelePisani 

We are a affiliate service, so our buy(køb) goals is set to measure converted traffic to our partners.

Comment: I mean if you know that the drop is only on analytics or your partners are actually having less revenue. To understand if there is an error in the tracking or if it is a real drop, since it is on all channels and not only on paid.